# Вытесняющий кэш для высоконагруженной системы?

Tags: java, кэширование

Уважаемые пользователи stackoverflow, здравствуйте!
Нужен ваш совет.
Очень нужно сделать тестовое задание.
Уровень знаний: +- основы JDBC и сервлетов без Spring.
Задание ниже. В какую сторону копать, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Задача 1. 
Вытесняющий кэш для высоконагруженной системы.
Введение: 
Бэкенд приложение с сравнительно большой нагрузкой должно иметь доступ к горячим данным для отображения и произведения несложных вычислений, перзистивное хранение осуществляется в СУБД. Любой доступ к горячим данным потенциально влечет за собой вызов запроса из СУБД, что является узким местом производительности. Для решения этой проблемы приложение должно иметь механизм хранения горячих данных, призванное сократить количество запросов к БД.
Что нужно сделать: 
Спроектировать и реализовать модуль реализующий вытесняющий кэш.
Модуль должен предоставлять публичное апи. Внутренняя реализация должна быть скрыта от других модулей.

Вариации: 
Структуры данных должны быть оптимизированы для массового паралельного доступа (память можно не экономить).
Структуры данных должны быть оптимизированы по памяти (скорость обращения, оптимизация работы сборщика мусора).
Структуры данных должны быть оптимизированы для хранения разных POJO типов.
Структуры данных должны быть оптимизированы для быстрой инвалидации. (скорость обновления по запросу).
Структуры данных должны быть спроектированы для быстрого поиска и вычислений.
(Повышенной сложности) Структуры данных должны иметь возможность быть разделены между двумя Java процессами.
Критерии оценки: 
Код должен быть написан согласно какому либо стандарту (ссылку можно прикрепить).
АПИ должно быть документировано в Java DOC.
Код должен быть покрыт юнит тестами.
Код должен быть покрыт нагрузочными тестами.

Comment: Простите, а на какой уровень это задание?

Comment: Junior :)
Мне тут сказали, что они на самом деле не сложные, "вам нужно просто:
1. Загуглить все умные слова и понять, что они значат
2. Упростить задачу (не переусложнять решение) - на самом деле оно на поверхности и достаточно просто гуглится (нужно будет изучить штук 5-6 ссылок в результатах Google)".
Сам я все еще в легком шоке

Comment: Это прикол какой-то. Junior) .

Comment: Именно реализовать самому? Или допускается, к примеру, сделать некую обертку вокруг какой-то библиотеки? Например, `guava - LoadingCache`?

Comment: Ну так делайте свое задание, мы здесь при чем? У вас есть конкретные вопросы по тому что описано выше?